# Weinre not displaying styles

Tags: weinre

I'm running weinre and ngrok to debug my https application on iOS Chrome.

I got it running great, I can inspect the html, and as I hover over stuff it gets highlighted on the page as you'd expect. My only problem is that styles are not showing up at all in the right-hand pane of Weinre.

Normally my Google-Fu provides something I can at least attempt to hunt down but I am at a bit of a loss here.

How can I get Weinre to show styles as I'd expect in the inspector when clicking on html elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, perhaps you can find a better tool than weinre - there's a list here: https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

From memory, problems with styles have typically been:

- using a stylesheet with a different origin than the page - the browser does not allow access to the styles in that case
- using media/etc queries with styles - the browser does not allow queries through these

Read "does not" as "did not back when weinre was written".